# how to get nstagramApi live mode?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

As I know, Instagram APIs do not allow user analysis. But how do many commercial apps use it to analyze and statistics users? How to go from sand-box mode to live mode ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login into the developer account .

Click on manage clients.

Go to the Permissions tab and start submission.

After your app has been reviewed and approved you will go for live .